# Simplifying $ \pi \sqrt{\frac{81}{\pi h}}\sqrt{\frac{81}{\pi h} + \pi h}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> In one of my exams, I got an expression:
> $$ \pi \sqrt{\frac{81}{\pi h}}\sqrt{\frac{81}{\pi h} + \pi h}$$ I got marked wrong and the final answer was
> $$9\sqrt{\frac{81}{h^2}+\pi h}$$

I have no idea how to simplify it further

Comment: $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ when $a,b\geq 0$

Comment: Your "final result" seems to be different from your first expression above, unless $h:=pi$...

Comment: I would like to type the full answer, but I do not know if solving basic math expressions is allowed by the forum rules... anyway, the hint that I've given above would be sufficient to help you to find the calculus error by yourself.

Comment: Also, for $x >0$, $x \sqrt{y} = \sqrt{x^2y}$

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct, unless the final step.
$$\pi \sqrt{\frac{81}{\pi h}} \sqrt{\frac{81}{\pi h}+\pi h} = \frac{\pi}{\pi h}\sqrt{81}{\sqrt{81+(\pi h)^2}} = 9\sqrt{\frac{81}{h^2}+\pi^2.}$$